# Moving project from one SVN to another while changing folder structure and preserving history

Tags: svn

Right now I'm trying to move projects from an old SVN (1.6.12) to a new one (1.8.13).
In the process I'd like to change the legacy folder-structure from:

```
[root]   
  -trunk
    -<subfolder1>
      -<projectfolder1.1>
      -...
    -<subfolder2>
      -<projectfolder2.1>
      -...
```

Into:

```
[root]
  -<project1.1>
    -trunk
    -branches
    -tags
  -<project2.1>
    -...
```

The tricky part (at least for me) is that I'm confused about how to preserve the history while doing so.
I've already read several articles about the [svnadmin dump](http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/doc/svn-book-html-chunk/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.dump.html) / [svndumpfilter](http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/doc/svn-book-html-chunk/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.tk.svndumpfilter) tools and even something about [manually fiddling around with the SVN-dump-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11210593/moving-from-one-svn-folder-structure-to-another) and now I'm wondering about:

- compatibility in respect of the versions mentioned above?
- what would be the correct roadmap to accomplish my goal?
- are there any tools available to do this? Maybe from client-side without having the need of SSHing and modifying on the server.

Any help/insight would be highly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all the others who also know how to *operate* but don't really know how to *administrate* a SVN, here is what finally worked for me:

First I followed @alroc's suggestion to restructure the original repo via client-side by using the standard SVN commands and moving the *old content* into the newly created **trunk** (thx and +1 for that!). Result:

```
[root]
  -trunk
    -<subfolder1>
      ...
  -<tmpfolder>
    -<project1>
      -trunk (old content moved here)
      -branches
      -tags
    -<project2>
      -...
```

After that I exported my repo via `svnadmin dump` and tried to filter out the content of my *tmpfolder* via `svndumpfilter --drop-empty-revs --renumber-revs include tmpfolder < DUMP_FILE > FILTERED_DUMP` but I  got the following error

> svndumpfilter: Invalid copy source path '/trunk/oldfolder/oldsubfolder'

because of the now missing links to the original locations which got lost during restructuring.
To get around this I've tried the following solutions

- added the `exclude [res1] [res2] [...]` switch to the `svnadmin dump` command - **same error**
- added the `--skip-missing-merge-sources` switch to the `svnadmin dump` command - **same error**
- added the `include [res1] [res2] [...]` switch to the `svnadmin dump` command - **filtering works but same error as above while importing**

Finally I found someone with the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9261625/svndumpfilter-fails-with-invalid-copy-source-path-error) who mentioned the use of [svndumpfilterIN](https://github.com/jasperlee108/svndumpfilterIN). After downloading this file to the *original-repo server* (and adding the right to execute) I executed it with the following command:
`python svndumpfilter.py ORG_REPO_DUMPFILE -r ORG_REPO_LOCATION -o FILTERED_DUMP_NAME include tmpfolder`.
This tool found all missing links via the specified `ORG_REPO_LOCATION` and untangled all dependencies while giving new and clean revision numbers for the filtered dump for me to import.

The only downside was that there was an unnecessary parent folder (*tempfolder*) I didn't want so I moved all projects into the root of the original-repo and renamed the original-trunk into **trunk2** to be able to exclude it in the svndumpfilterIN-tool.

```
[root]
  -trunk2 (renamed)
    -<subfolder1>
      ...
  -<project1>
    -trunk
    -branches
    -tags
  -<project2>
    -...
```

Lastly I filtered via `python svndumpfilter.py ORG_REPO_DUMPFILE -r ORG_REPO_LOCATION -o FILTERED_DUMP_NAME exclude trunk2` and imported this filterd dump into my new repository with `svnadmin load`.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Don't do this in one step.

Long answer: That's a *lot* of change to attempt in a single pass *while*  preserving history and everything else.

Take it one step at a time:

1. Reorganize the repository on your current server using the appropriate `svn` commands - `svn mv`, `svn cp`, `svn rename`, etc. You can do this either against URLs or from within a working copy (or both) - this can be accomplished 100% client-side. This will preserve history (as long as you do it properly).
2. After the reorg is complete, use the `svnadmin dump`/`svnadmin load` cycle to migrate your repository to the new server. You can use `svnadmin rdump` to create the dump file from the source using a client computer, but you do need access to the server to `svnadmin load` on the new one.

As always, make sure you have good backups (test a restore!) and try this on a test version of your repository before doing it on one that matters.

Comment: This is definitely dangerous to try to do all at once.  I recommend migrating to the new server *before* doing the re-organization, though.  That way, if you mess something up during the re-org, your source repo is still pristine so you can simply delete the new repo and start over.

Comment: Anything you mess up in the reorg can be undone. And you should have a clean backup of it anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll give it a try. Just to clarify: I never meant to solve my problem in one step but wasn't sure about a good starting point.